# Can I freshen my clothes on the ISS with a clothes line?

Tags: iss, vacuum, long-duration, hygiene

There are a number of questions about washing clothes on the ISS, the short answer is that they do **NOT** wash them.

- [Nudism in space: Why wear clothes anyway?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24206/109)
- [Washing clothes in space: are there any technical challenges?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/653/109)
- [Laundry on the ISS](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13893/109)

Answers that go into detail about the challenges talk about the different methods of washing clothes on Earth and how the are problematic in space. When I read them, I realized that washing clothes on Earth is much like what is going to happen to [Elon Musk's Tesla, just from being in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24365/109)

So the question becomes; If I hang my dirty clothes out on a clothesline, from the ISS, how long will it take for them to be freshed?

Maybe the space exposure damages the cloth to fast to make this practical, I don't know.

Obviously I am oversimplifying the solution, as you can't just open a window run the dirty clothes out on a line, but say you had a small air lock with a retractable clothes line...

Comment: You want to hang them on the outside of the ISS?

Comment: @Hobbes, yes why not?

Comment: just asking for clarification as you didn't specify it in the question.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Are you washing them first and hanging them out to dry, or just running out the dirty clothes?

Comment: @Punintended just running out the dirty clothes. Oils and such should evaporate.

Comment: Possibly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8743/26446

Comment: Hanging the clothes would be difficult in zero gravity.

Comment: That's what clothespins are for!

Comment: I'm tempted to just build a space simulation rig to test this but I feel like I'd end up with vacuum pump pill that smells like sweaty socks